# How to interpret the hinge function for multivariate adaptive regression splines？

Tags: machine-learning, nonlinear-regression, multivariate-regression

[image]

I do not understand why we need a reflected pair (t-x)+ for MARS. 
Could you please interpret more about the hinge function?